# Puppet waits for never ending bash script

Tags: linux, bash, puppet, daemon

I have bash script that starts ethereum miner. The script also starts to show log of what it's doing and won't stop until I give the quit signal for it.
Because it doesn't stop without user input puppet won't see that the script has started and keeps waiting for signal that the script has been finished.
Now how can I make it so that the script sends signal it has finished?

It would be nice extra feature that puppet could also stop the already running script and start a new one if I update the files, rather than just start a new script on the side of the old one.

This is the part of puppet module that starts the script:

```
exec { 'run_miner':
    command => '/tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/miner_startstop.sh',
    provider => 'shell',
    cwd => '/tmp/puppetethereum/claymore/',
    require => File['miner_skripti'],
}
```

This is for a school project so dirty methods are allowed.

Edit.
I have tried this template of start-stop-daemon, but puppet still waits for the signal that the script has started:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Quick start-stop-daemon example, derived from Debian /etc/init.d/ssh
set -e

# Must be a valid filename
NAME=ethereumminer
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
#This is the command to be run, give the full pathname
DAEMON=sudo bash /tmp/claymore/mine.sh
DAEMON_OPTS="--baz=quux"

export PATH="${PATH:+$PATH:}/usr/sbin:/sbin"

case "$1" in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
        echo "."
    ;;
  stop)
        echo -n "Stopping daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --pidfile $PIDFILE
        echo "."
    ;;
  restart)
        echo -n "Restarting daemon: "$NAME
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --oknodo --retry 30 --pidfile $PIDFILE
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    echo "."
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: "$1" {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: You really should be configuring this as a service.

Comment: @jordanm I added the script I have tried, but puppet still keeps waiting for the script.

Comment: The script you have presented looks like a SysV initscript.  You should verify that it works correctly (hint: if it does not exit quickly then it doesn't) before you worry about making puppet use it.  If this is at all the right thing for your system, then probably you want to add the `--background` option to your `start-stop-daemon` commands that also specify `--start`.

Comment: You should furthermore install it in the correct place and way for your system (possibly via Puppet) and then use a Puppet `Service` resource to configure the system to run it.